# How to check if workbook exists?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable (WB). I assigned the activeworkbook to that variable.

I want to check if WB is set to activeworkbook or if it is still empty. If it's present, I will close the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

you can check is object variable is set by condition

```
if wb is nothing then .... ' not set
if not wb is nothing then .... ' is set
```

your case

```
if not wb is nothing then
  if wb.name = thisworkbook.name then wb.close
end if
```

or in one line

```
if not wb is nothing then if wb.name = thisworkbook.name then wb.close
```